# Advanced multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have something like this:

```
<Controls:ToggleRectangleButton.Visibility>
   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiButtonCheckedToVisibilityConverter}">
      <Binding ElementName="btDayAndNightsLinesTickets" Path="IsButtonChecked" />
      <Binding ElementName="btSchoolSemester" Path="IsButtonChecked" />
   </MultiBinding>
</Controls:ToggleRectangleButton.Visibility>
```

MultiButtonCheckedToButtonEnabledConverter's convert method

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool visible = false;
    foreach (object value in values)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((bool)value == true) visible = true;
        }
    }   
    if (visible)
    {
        return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        return System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

So it mean that if at least one of buttons passed as parameters has IsButtonChecked property set to true -> show control. Otherwise hide it.

I want to add some functionality, that is condition:

> if ( otherButton.IsChecked ) return System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

So if otherButton is checked hide control (independently of the other conditions). I want to be able to set more "otherButtons" than 1 (if at least one of "otherButtons" is checked -> Hide).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class MultiButtonCheckedToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool visible = false;
        int trueCount = (int)parameter;

        for (int i = 0; i < trueCount; i++)
        {
            if ((bool)values[i]) 
            {
                visible = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (visible)
        {
            for (int i = trueCount; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!(bool)values[i])
                {
                    visible = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (visible)
        {
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Test">
    <Button.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiButtonCheckedToVisibilityConverter}">
            <MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
            </MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
            <Binding ElementName="btDayAndNightsLinesTickets" Path="IsChecked" />
            <Binding ElementName="btSchoolSemester" Path="IsChecked" />
            <Binding ElementName="btOther1" Path="IsChecked" />
            <Binding ElementName="btOther2" Path="IsChecked" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.Visibility>
</Button>
<ToggleButton Name="btDayAndNightsLinesTickets">btDayAndNightsLinesTickets</ToggleButton>
<ToggleButton Name="btSchoolSemester">btSchoolSemester</ToggleButton>
<ToggleButton Name="btOther1">btOther1</ToggleButton>
<ToggleButton Name="btOther2">btOther2</ToggleButton>
```

The idea is to tell to converter how many buttons shows the control. If this count is not a constant you can refactor converter to receive count as a first binding.

Answer (score 0):

the order of the binding will be kept in the converter code. 
you can check the  `object[] values` using an Index and implement your logic according to it.

for example :

```
if((values[0] is bool) && ((bool)values[0]))
{
    //DoSomething
}
```

Comment: You should not provide button as a value for a binding, because this kind of binding will never listen to button's properties.